Referencing cell by using table column and named range row
I have the following table.

Every TOTALs row is a named range as can be seen from the formula bar.
In addition, i have multiple sheets with the same table and the same named range (local named range).  New sheets may be added and removed over the course of time.
I would like to sum across all rows to get Totals monthly gross across all spread sheets (including new spread sheets that are added).
As i don't know how to do this using a formula + named ranges (i don't want to use cell addresses as they may change and become a nightmare to maintain), i'd like to use VBA
I would like in VBA to be able to write a udf to sum multiple sheets that have a named table and total rows ranges of the same name.  It would be easiest and more robust i feel to be able to use structured refences to get the table column, and then the named range to pinpoint the cell, or vice versa.   is this possible without having to use cell addresses or position/index (again the sheets may be volatiles in the sense that rows may be added and removed, thus shifting the 'totals' row from sheet to sheet, as well as sheets being removed and added.
Thanks much

EDIT 1:
@MGonet. i want to sum the total rows shown above, but across all sheet..to effectively get a yearly total of totals rows.  So effectively i'd end up with something that looks like this

where the first cell would be the sum of the cell intersecting the GROSS column and the named range 'jan_total' for all sheets, then below that would be the the sum of intersection of Expense column and 'jan_toal' range, and so on.  I have managed to do this with vba, but im not sure its the best, easiest way. one other note, is all sheets i care to sum begin with an 'e_':
Public Function totals_sum(month As String, field As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tbl As ListObject, rngCol As Range, rngNR As Range
    Dim sumTotal As Double
    Dim x As Variant
    On Error GoTo proc_err
    'Application.Volatile True
    
    For Each ws In Application.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, "e_") Then
            Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(1) 'TODO: name table based on sheet name
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rngCol = tbl.ListColumns(field).DataBodyRange
            If rngCol Is Nothing Then GoTo loop_continue
            On Error GoTo proc_err
            Set rngNR = ws.Range(month & "_total")
            'range row will be table NR range row - table top
            'Debug.Print ws.Name & ":" & tbl.Range.Cells(rngNR.row - (tbl.Range.row - 1), rngCol.Column)
            sumTotal = sumTotal + tbl.Range.Cells(rngNR.row - (tbl.Range.row - 1), rngCol.Column)
            'Debug.Print ws.Name & ":" & sumTotal
        End If
loop_continue:
    Next
    Debug.Print sumTotal
    payroll_sum = sumTotal

proc_exit:
    Set tbl = Nothing
    Set rngCol = Nothing
    Set rngNR = Nothing
    Exit Function
    
proc_err:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
    Resume proc_exit
End Function

and so now with the above code, i can put the following in in the upper left most cell:  =totals_sum(B$2,$A3) to get the calculated total for Gross for Jan across all sheets.

Why not use countifs() based on the month to get each month total and then countifs() with the year to get the annual total? Same logic applies for the quarter totals etc

Why don't you use a pure data table (without subtotals) and then use pivot tables to get the subtotals - per year, quarter, month?

Give an example of what you want to sum (with sheet names).

@MGonet i've edited by question to add more context and hopefully answer your question.

@iKe this sheet is also an input form for capturing gross and various expenses paid out.  so each week, someone enters that data, and need to use it for payroll - so i need it to be both input and somewhat real time reporting.  i was thinking about PowerQuery..bu im not sure how to dynamically query say all sheets starting with 'e_' for the tables im interested in.  im very new to this vba, excel and much less power query (im a python and infra guy mostly).

Mixing data (input) and presentation layer is nearly always an issue when Excel files become larger or have more users. Why not have one big table - on a "data input"-sheet adding a "Type" column reflecting the sheet names - and then use a pivot table on a "presentation"-sheet (no power query nececssary) to achieve what you want.

Overall, the code looks good. Only the name of the function is incorrect, it should be: totals_sum instead of payroll_sum. You can also simplify the line:
sumTotal = sumTotal + tbl.Range.Cells(rngNR.row - (tbl.Range.row - 1), rngCol.Column)
into:
sumTotal = sumTotal + Intersect(rngNR, rngCol).Value

yes, i had changed it before posting so it made a little more sense and readable.  Is this the best way of doing this? i am trying to minimize things breaking if cells shift around or new sheets are added.
